# How can I get the MapReduce Jobs source codes generated by the Hive compiler?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I'd like to know what is the code generated by the compiler of SQL [Hive](http://hive.apache.org/) ( i.e. if I execute one sql sentence I'd like to see the code of MapReduce jobs generated by compiler of SQL hive).

How can I get it?

Answer (score 15):

For Hive, it serializes the physical plan into an xml file (page 15 in http://www.slideshare.net/nzhang/hive-anatomy). So, I do not think that users can get the real source codes for hadoop. To get the code, you can try YSmart (http://ysmart.cse.ohio-state.edu/). It is a translator that will translate your sql queries to the java source code for hadoop. You can use the online version of the YSmart. Just submit the schema and your query, you will be able to view and download the java code.

Comment: Thank you very much!!  I had just found that the plan was serialized in xml files and they are store in hdfs filesystem in  the directory /tmp/hive-${user.name}/ by default. And you confirm it. In other hand, thank you by the project ysmart its can help me. What happens is that I'm interesting in understand the proccess perfomed by the Hive compiler since parser until the execute. Do you have any information that can help me? Thank very much.

Comment: besides the presentation I mentioned, probably you want to look at the source code of the Hive (start from `org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(String, boolean)`). Compliance work is done in `org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer` and you can take a look at `org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer.analyzeInternal(ASTNode)`. Also, check `org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.optimizer.Optimizer` for optimizers. Hope these information can help you.