# MR code from Hive

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive

I am learning Hadoop and was learning about Hive in recent past. Its like a SQL query which can be used instead of MR java code. My tutor said that Hive produces MR java code behind the scene, which in turn is exported as jar file and then it is ran on top of HDFS filesystem. But, he was not sure if we can get the MR code produced by Hive. I was reading Definitive guide and nothing was discussed about it. I wanted to know is it really so? As I think if we can get the MR code then that code can be refined further to achieve many other things (means can be customized for other tasks).

I know I am just in learning stage and should wait before asking or jumping to conclusions but was curious. I think if even above concept is correct then catching MR code should be possible. I am .Net C# developer and not familiar with Java and not an expert in Relational DBs, wanted to tell only if it matters.

Comment: I don't think you can simply get the MR codes from the generated DAG. However, this answer might help you to get further:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/9083923/1050422

Comment: @LorandBendig: Its exactly what I am looking for. I think it was me who was searching for `MR` instead of `MapReduce` in google and failed to produce proper results. Thanks.