# MapReduce code generated by Hive

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive

Where does Apache HiveQL store the Map/Reduce code it generates?

Comment: Duplicate question, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14191762/mr-code-from-hive or http://stackoverflow.com/a/9083923/1050422

Answer (score 6):

I believe Hive doesn't really generate Map/Reduce code in the sense as you could get from Java, because it is interpreted by the Hive query planner.

If you want to get an idea of what kind of operations your Hive queries generate, you could prefix your queries with `EXPLAIN` and you will see the abstract syntax tree, the dependency graph, and the plan of each stage. More info on `EXPLAIN` [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/Hive/languagemanual-explain.html).

If you really want to see some Map/Reduce jobs, you could try [YSmart](http://ysmart.cse.ohio-state.edu/) which will translate your HiveQL statements into working Java Map/Reduce code. I haven't used it personally, but I know people who have and said good things about it.

Comment: FYI .... similarly PIG also supports [EXPLAIN](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html#EXPLAIN).

Answer (score -1):

It seems that Hive change this method every query execution.

http://hive.apache.org/docs/r0.9.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/exec/Task.html#execute(org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.DriverContext)